# Правописание слова "суб(б)ота"

Tags: этимология, удвоенные-буквы

Почему в слове суббота мы пишем удвоенное б, хотя на произношении это никак не сказывается?
В современных европейских языках такого удвоения нет (Sabado/Sabato), только в мёртвой латыни (Sabbato).
Можно ли упростить правописание слова и приблизить его к обычному произношению? Какие для этого существуют препятствия.

Субота (др.-рус., укр., блр., серб.),
събота (болг.), сабота (макед.),
sobota (пол., чеш., словен., слов.),
subota (хорв.).

Таким образом, современное русское написание круто расходится с общеславянской традицией, да и с общеевропейской.
Церковнославянский вариант, заимствованный из латыни, безвозвратно устарел и никого и ни к чему не обязывает. 
Современная семантика суботы проста : особый промежуточный день между рабочими буднями и воскресеньем. Су/бо/та - день домашних забот, работ и хлопот. Свою религиозную окраску субота, как день недели, давно утратила. В церковной практике, конечно, используется ЦСЯ, но никто вне церкви не употребляет его орфографию, со множеством устаревших и отмененных  букв.
Кстати, можно посмотреть в словаре, как пишется слово субота на иврите. Шбт.

Comment: Вообще-то латынь тут рядом не лежало. Шаббат - еврейское слово.

Comment: Суббота

**Этимология**

Происходит от семитск., ср.: арам. šabbǝtā или др.-еврейск. šabbāt. Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера.  [Wiktionary](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/суббота)

Латынь тут ни при чём. Мы же не утверждаем, что *чай*, к примеру -- русское слово. Хотя оно и пришло именно через русский язык к некоторым народам Севера. Чай -- изначально китайский напиток и слово китайское. 

Этак можно утверждать, что и "менеджер" или "штангенциркуль" -- русские слова.

Comment: Вот вам ещё похожая аналогия. Много иностранных слов пришло из русского языка (точнее, через русский язык) народам Азии, вошедшим в Советский Союз и получавшим образование там. Так и в огромную Римскую Империю вошло много народов. А языками науки долгое время были латынь и греческий.

Вообще-то не вижу проблемы в том, чтобы писать слово "суббота" с двумя "б".

Comment: >Мы же не утверждаем, что чай, к примеру -- русское слово  

Nikolja, вы слегка запутались. Для "северных народов" чай - вполне русское слово. Поскольку заимствовано из русского или посредством русского. В этимологических изысканиях этого достатчно.    
Но "суббота" в русский попало НЕ из латыни и НЕ посредством латыни. Древнееврейский, греческий, церковнославянский - это все годится в той или иной мере. Но не латынь, которая скорее всего сама слово из греческого заимствовала.

Comment: >Но "суббота" в русский попало НЕ из латыни и НЕ посредством латыни.
Именно это я и хотел сказать.

Слово "суббота" вошло во многие языки. Откуда? **Grumant** говорит о латыни. А я хочу заметить, что слово изначально -- семитское. Т.е. заимствовано из иврита или, возможно, родственного ивриту арамейского языка.

Comment: >Церковнославянские тексты переводили и правили с греческих и латинских источников  

Главным образом - с греческого. Влияние собственно Римской церкви на славянских Балканах уже тогда было минимальным, хотя до Великого Раскола еще оставалось какое-то время. Но это к слову. Ну пусть даже переводили с латыни, это не основание объявлять субботу заимствованием из неё.

Comment: @mikka, дойдет очередь и до России!
> С. Романюк. Царь-пушка (2007) «Божиею милостию царь и великий князь Федор Иванович государь и самодержавец всея **великия Росия**».

>Н. К. Гудзий. История ... (1938) «И с того времени князь великий Владимер Всеволодович наречеся Манамах, **царь великия Росия**...
... и страна наречется **светлая Росия**…

Д.И. Иловайский. Начало Руси (1876) ...встречаем иногда Боспор или Керчь под именем города «**Росия**» (например, в договоре Генуэзцев с Греками в 1170 г.
ж
И. Н. Масленников. Книга записи ... (1819-1833) **Росия** взяла над Персию верх.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

дополнение господину, который "заглянул в онлайн словарь: идиш и иврит"
В иврите (мой второй язык) буквы могут удваиваться в зависимости от грамматической формы слова. Такие случаи обозначаются на письме точкой внутри буквы. Так, в слове ШаБаТ - пишется одна буква "бет" с точкой внутри - произносится ШаББаТ. это удвоение трудно услышать (как и в русском).
Интересно, как грамматическое явление языка иврит, где оно имеет некое смысловое значение, сохранилось в русском, где оно непонятно и уж точно не имеет никакого смыслового значения...
В иврите та же буква БЕЗ точки внутри произносится "в". В идише та же буква всегда "б"п
От того же Шабат в русском есть и слово "шабаш"

Comment: Шолом, иосиф

> как грамматическое явление языка иврит... сохранилось в русском

Хороший вопрос... Если очень кратко, то виноваты как вседа греки, переводившие Пятикнижие (письменное, естественно)  и передавшие удвоение согласного двойной графемой, в дальнейшем частично утерянной в разных словах-наследниках и переводах, но сохранившейся в русском.

Насчет грамматического смысла удвоения в иврите - не совсем понял.

>От того же Шабат в русском есть и слово "шабаш  

Неочевидно. Но об этом не здесь.

Comment: Иосиф подтвердил мое мнение о совершенной ненужности в русской орфографии слова субота двойного написания б, и я принял его ответ. Вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Препятствие только одно. Существующие правила.
Есть много случаев, которые, возможно, следовало бы упростить, но правила обязаны быть консервативными.

Answer (score -1):

Можно утверждать, что "менеджер" или "штангенциркуль" -- русские слова или точнее славянские или ещё точнее праславянские или вульгарная латынь.
менеджер – meneger > manit-rukj – манить рукой (слав.)(инв. ger, редукция k/g), «манить рукой» значит управлять.
также как «манипулятор» - искусственная (автоматическая) рука (от лат. manipulus – горсть, пригоршня, manus – рука) ? 
manipulus – manit – palka-(us) – манить палкой (слав.)(пропуск k), что более похоже на истину.
штангенциркуль состоит из двух слов «штанга» и «циркуль»
штанга (от нем. Stange – стержень, прут) БСЭ > stergen – стержень (слав.)(перест. n/g, пропуск r)
циркуль – curculus – круг (лат.) > crug-(us) – круг (слав.)(перест. c/r, редукция g/c)

суббота – Shabbath > sobirat-banja – собирать баню (слав.)(ред. s/sh, замена n/th), срав. bath – баня (англ.)
Отсюда удвоение b.

«Суббота - лицо Сатурна однозначно проглядывается в Saturday (англ.) и Saturni (лат.). Русское название «суббота», el Sabado (исп.), Sabato (итал.) и Samedi (фр.) восходят к ивритскому «Шаббат», означающему "покой, отдых". В этом смысле с Шаббатом удачно перекликается одно из астрологических значений Сатурна – неподвижность, концентрация. Интересно, что славянские языки, ни с того ни с сего, единодушны с латинскими, их суббота тоже родом от "Шаббата". Lauantai (фин.), Lördag(шв.), Loverdag (дат.) сходны с древненемецким Laugardagr и означают "день омовения", откуда мы узнаём, что раз в неделю древние мылись обязательно.  На хинди суббота - День Сатурна.»

«Любопытно, что само слово "неделя" калька с греческого apracos, т.е. не-делающий, не-дельный, праздный.»
Совсем не так.
Apracos > na-dlca > ne-delca – неделька (слав.)(проп. n, замена d/p)

http://www.liveastrology.org/dni_nedeli.htm

Lauf - 1. бег 2. спорт. забег, заезд 3. ствол (огнестрельного оружия) 4. течение (времени) > lov/stvol/rok/lavina/liven/tikanj/srok - лов/ствол/рок/лавина/ливень/тикание/срок (слав.)( редукция v/f; инв. Lauf, пропуск st, редукция v/f; редукция r/l, k/f)

У италиков и славян суббота всегда была «банным днём».
 Tabula Bantina – оскская табличка, где Bantina (оск.) > banja – tina - банный день (слав.)

Tabula Abellano
Транскрипция итальянских исследователей:

pst.feнhнs.ps. fнsnam.am
fret.eнseн.tereн.nep.abel
lans.nep.nvlans. pнdum

Частичный перевод Tabula Abellano:

Traduzione in latino: "Post muros qui fanum circumdant, in eo territorio neque Abellani neque Nolani quicquam aedificaverint"
Traduzione in italiano: "Dietro il muro che circonda il santuario, in quest'area nй gli abitanti di Abella nй gli abitanti di Nola (hanno il permesso di) edificare".
Traduzione in inglese: "Behind the walls which go around the sanctuary, in this area neither the inhabitants of Abella nor the inhabitants of Nola (are allowed to construct) anything.

Перевод с английского на русский:
«Позади стен, которые располагаются вокруг святилища, в этой области никому из жителей Абелла ни жителей Нола, (не позволено строить) что-нибудь».
Комментарий:
Строительная тематика – излюбленная тема этрускологов.
Мною была проведена попытка перевести три списка осков с помощью славянских языков или вульгарной латыни. Вульгарная латынь позволяет переводить латинизированные оскские тексты. Текст из Помпей и  Tabula Bantina я изучал долго, делал различные варианты переводов, но все безрезультатно. Наконец, совсем недавно, я получил перевод, который меня совершенно потряс. Текст из Помпей и  Tabula Bantina практически являются не юридическим документом, а описанием постройки бани и обрядом омовения.
Помпейский текст я озаглавил как «Постройка бани в г. Помпеи» а Tabula Bantina как «Банный день», что, кстати, видно из заголовка таблицы невооруженным глазом, если конечно читать его на народной латыни Ban-tina (банный день). Как известно, tina по этруски означает «день», впрочем, как и по славянски.
При раскопках в г. Помпеи были обнаружены фрески эротического содержания, которые американские исследователи трактуют как настенную живопись публичных домов. Таких публичных домов в Помпее было множество. 
Но случай сам по себе ничего не дает. Требуется сопоставление фактов в существующей проблеме.
Вот тогда и появился вопрос: почему увеселительные заведения, а не бани, например? Ведь город Помпея расположен у горы Везувий. И окрестности Везувия  в древности, возможно, были богаты термальными источниками. Ведь это естественные бани, которые не требуют специального отопления !
Перечень банных комнат, которые существовали в римских банях подтвердили мои догадки.
frigidarius - холодная баня –фригидарий (лат.)/ fligi-tari - влажная тара - влажный или холодный  зал (слав.)
tepidarius - теплая баня –тепидарий (лат.)/ tep[l]i-tar - теплая тара
caldarius - горячая баня- кальдарий (лат.)/ gar-tari - горячая тара (горячий зал).
В Помпеях существовал мясной рынок, который назывался малеллум. Смотрим перевод:
macellum - мацеллум (мясной рынок)/ mace-run – мясной рынок (слав.).
И все эти слова без усилий переводятся на славянский язык (народная латынь).
Таким образом, помпейские бани – это прообраз современных vip-саун.
Надпись из Помпеи

Оригинал:

C*AARIDANS*C*EVTIVCAM*ПAAM
CEDEIIAU*ПVMAIIAV*TD*USTAA
MEN TVR*RERER*EUSAK*EUTIVCAR
C*CIUNIKIUS*MD*KCAUSSTVD*ПVMП
AIIS*TDUUθVM*EKAK*KVM BEN
NIEUS*TANCINVR*VПSANNAM
RERER*USURVM*ПDV8AT TER

Образец перевода этрускологами оскской надписи из г. Помпеи I век до н.э:
Оскский текст:
Транскрипция:
v·aadirans·v·eutiu vam·paam
vereiiaί·púmpaiianai·tr·istaa
men tud·de ded·eίsak·eίtiu vad
v·viίnikiis·mr·kvaίsstur·púmpaiians.
trίίbum·e kak·kúm ben nieίs
tangi nud·úpsan nam·
de ded·ίsίdum·prúfatted

Перевод этрускологов:

«Вибий Адриан, сын Вибия, деньги, что он дал обществу молодежи города Помпеи, эти деньги В. Виникий, сын Мары, квестор помпейский, приказал потратить на строительство этого дома и утвердил это»

Перевод с помощью славянских языков:

Постройка бани в г. Помпеи

«Великий Адриан, великий явити вам баню, ввереную помпейцам. Триста человек тут дело делали.  Её заключил, её дивную воду великий Виникий Мара квестор помпейский. Требу, её как Куму (Лукумону) пчелы приносят, деньги надо. Написано нами дело деланное всюду одобрено»

Комментарии:

v aadirans – великий Адриан
veutiu vam – великий явил вам
paam – баня
púmpaiianai, púmpaiians – помпейцы
vereiiaί – ввереный
tristaa – триста
men tud – человек тут
de ded – дело делали
eί sak – её заключил
eί tiu vad – ее дивную воду
v viίnikiis – великий Виникий
mr –Мара
kvaίsstur – квестор
trίίbum – треба (дань)
e kak – её как
kúm – Кум (Лукумон) - правитель
ben nieίs –пчелы приносят
tangi nud –деньги надо
úpsan nam – описанный нами
ίsίdum – всюду
prúfatted – правится (одобрено)

Еще аналогия:
Транскрипция:

MARAS • STAIIS • BANTTIE •
LUСKIS • DEKITIS • MARAE
СIK TVRRAI • DVNUM • DED

Перевод автора:

«Марсу ставил Банный день.
Лучинки делал, окатил маранные
щёки, в рог дунул деду»

Комментарий:

Ритуал омовения у осков статуи бога Марса.

Таким образом, у евреев шаббат – день отдыха, ничегонеделания (неделька по-русски), а у славян – день омовения, баня. И кто у кого заимствовал слово шаббат вполне понятно. Слово шаббат заимствовано в древнееврейский из праславянского языка.